# How to split and refactor a large function so it would do only one thing?

Tags: javascript, performance, design-patterns

I am learning about clean and maintainable code. I heard that functions should be no more than 20 lines long (*preferably 5 - 10 lines*). I have come across this Bob Martin quote where he said:

> “The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that”.

And also this one

> “Functions should do one thing. They should do it well. They should do it only”.

This all sounds great in theory but when a new programmer starts out - their code looks nothing like the above. And I'm not sure how to start to refactor this function to be small and do only one thing.

This function is taken from my Cash Register app that I'm making using Vue.js + Laravel. When a user clicks on the green "Pay" button - there are many things that need to happen so how can my function still be small?

`<button @click="processPayment('cash')">Pay</button>`

1. Check if a user has ordered a regular sandwich and show a notification to offer a special sandwitch.
2. Give some "special" tables a discount
3. Validate if there are any items selected
4. If there has been a discount, check if there is also a comment - else show an error
5. Deal with Food Delivery services (special treatment)
6. Call the Pay backend API
7. Refresh all the data
8. Call the Print Receipt API
9. Start Table Timers (so we know how long the customer has been waiting for their order)
10. Play the new order sound (ding!)
11. Reset everything at the end

Whoa! That's a lot of things going on there when the `Pay` button is pressed. How can we possibly make this function do only one thing and be short? I'm confused.

Here is my long method:

`````
async processPayment(payment_method, options = null)
{
    this.checkIfOrderContainsRegularSandwitch()

    if (store.orderContainsRegularSandwitch && !store.isConfirmedOrder) {
        store.showOrderConfirmationModal = true
        return
    }

    // comment for special tables
    if (this.specialTableSelected()) {
        store.orderComment = store.pickedTable.description
    }

    /**
     * discounts for special tables
     */

    if (this.specialTableSelected() && payment_method != 'Uber' && payment_method != 'DoorDash') {
        Order.applySpecialTableDiscounts()
    }


    if (!store.orderedItems.length) {
        CashRegister.reset()
        return
    }

    if (store.order.discount > 0 && !store.orderComment) {
        if (payment_method != 'Uber' && payment_method != 'DoorDash' ) {
            store.infoModalTitle = this.lang('order_with_discount')
            store.infoModalMessage = this.lang('order_with_discount_msg')
            store.showInfoModal = true

            return;
        }
    }

    if (payment_method == 'Uber') {
        store.isUber = true
        store.orderComment = 'Uber'
    }

    if (payment_method == 'DoorDash') {
        store.isDoorDash = true
        store.orderComment = 'DoorDash'
    }

    // 30% discount for Uber or DoorDash
    if (payment_method == 'Uber' || payment_method == 'DoorDash') {
        store.orderDiscount = 30
        store.orderDiscountType = '%'

        Order.applyTotalDiscount()
        Order.calculateTotals()
    }

    if (!store.order.isPaid)
    {
        store.isPaymentLoading = true

        // Save the order
        let order_id = await OrderApi.pay({
            order:          store.order,
            orderedItems:   store.orderedItems,
            payment_method: payment_method,
            table:          store.pickedTable.description,
            table_id:       store.pickedTable.id,
            order_mode:     store.orderMode,
            order_comment:  store.orderComment,
            takeaway_time : store.takeawayTime,
            is_takeaway:    (store.isTakeaway) ? 1 : 0,
            ml_delivery_phone:  store.MLDeliveryPhone,
            is_ml_delivery:    (store.isMLDelivery) ? 1 : 0,
            applied_discount: store.orderDiscount,
            applied_discount_type: store.orderDiscountType,
            has_coupon: store.hasCoupon,
            pay_cash: options?.pay_cash ?? 0,
            pay_card: options?.pay_card ?? 0,
        })

        order_id = order_id.data

        store.isPaymentLoading = false


        // Refresh order history
        OrderHistory.getTotalOrderHistory({
            date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        })


        // Refresh tables
        Data.getTables().then(({ data }) => {
            store.tables = data
        })


        // Refresh popular today
        Data.getPopularToday().then(({ data }) => {
            store.popularToday = data
        })


        // Print receipt
        if (store.shouldPrint) {
            await this.printReceipt({})
        }

        // Refresh Bar Items
        Data.getBarItems().then(({ data }) => {
            store.barItems = data

            if (store.barItems.length) {
                store.isBarCarouselMinimized = false
            }
        })

        if (payment_method != 'Uber' && payment_method != 'DoorDash') {
            if (store.order.payment_method != 'Pay later') {
                if (store.settings.settings?.table_timers == true) {
                    this.startTableTimer(store.pickedTable.id, order_id, 0)
                }
            }
        }

        if (store.settings.settings.new_order_notification_sound) {
            this.playNewOrderSound(store.orderedItems)
        }

        CashRegister.reset(order_id)
    }
},
````
`````

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The core of your problem is that the name of the function is wrong. You're not processing a payment, you're processing an order. Part of that order is payment. You put way too much logic into one function. Please provide the `CashRegister`, `Order`, `OrderHistory` and other relevant classes in your code.

Comment: By what I'm seeing so far, I'd suggest you leave this project alone for a while and practice first with cutting-up smaller projects into functions. Refactoring this entire project is going to take a while.

Comment: Looks like there could be one `handleClick` function that contains 11 calls to other functions.

Comment: You've listed 11 things the "`pay()`" function should do - Great!  
Write 11 functions to do just that, all called from within the "`pay()`" function, and use descriptive names = compartmentalization, "easier" to figure out where a problem might be, and more! :)